# Prove that if $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)=0$ and $f(x) \ge 0$ $\forall x \ge 0$, then $\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ is finite.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I have a conjecture which is "if $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)=0$ and $f(x) \ge 0$ $\forall x \ge 0$, then $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ is finite."
Here is my attempt
Since $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)=0$, $\exists m>0: f(x)<1 \forall x >m:$

On the other hand, we also have: Forall $x>m$ we have
$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt = \int_{0}^{m}f(t)dt + \int_{m}^{x} f(t)dt < \int_{0}^{m}1 dt  = 1+(x-m)$
But when I take limitation, the strict equality does not hold.
Any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 6):

It is not true. Take $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+x}$.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @Pipnap: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Not true. For example $f(x)=(x+1)^{-1/2}$. $f\to 0$ When $x\to \infty$ and $f>0$ but $$\int_0^\infty(x+1)^{-1/2} dx=\frac{1}{2}\left (\lim_{x\to\infty}(x+1)^{+1/2}-1\right) =+\infty.$$

Comment: thank you very much